# iOS Mobile Safari not liking the ftp:// protocol

Tags: ios, ftp, mobile-safari

Having a hard time finding much about this doing a search. Is it just me or does Safari on iOS not know what to do with a `ftp://` link? It seems to work on Android, but tapping the link in Mobile Safari just tells me:

> You do not have permission to view "/".

This is an FTP that requires authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Try to type:

```
ftp://username:password@host
```

This should work.

Mobile Safari is a browser with limited functionality. Personally, i dislike it. It is good browser for web-surfing and stuff, but it's not very useful for developer.

Comment: Yeah, the problem though is that I am forced to add the ftp link on our website, and I need to prompt the user for the auth info. So the above solution won't work. This is a problem.

Comment: @NicHubbard Try to install another browser. Chrome, whatever

Comment: But we can't expect our website users to know to go download another browser or an FTP app. Many are clueless and just want to tap the link to login. I submitted a radar for this. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @NicHubbard So, you prompt the user for the auth info. Then you want to redirect the user to his ftp root. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yeah, that is the general idea. It working perfect on desktop and Android. I would no go this route if my IT department wasn't in control.

Comment: I have one idea. You can create the link of ftp://username:password@host format on-fly and redirect user, but it's very unsafe.

Comment: Yeah, but even that won't work. We have different users needing to access it, each with different auth info, so I can't hardcode it.

Comment: Yeah... I suppose that's an iOS problem. You should report about it to your IT department, I think.

Comment: Yeah, that is the option I am pursuing.